# What a stochastic process with constant variance is called?

Tags: terminology, stochastic-processes, stationarity

Consider a stochastic process $\left( x_t \right)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ with auto-covariance function $k(t, t') = \mathbb{E}[(x_t - \mu_t) (x_{t'} - \mu_{t'})]$ where $\mu_{t} = \mathbb{E}[x_t]$.

Suppose $k(t, t)$ is constant, meaning that the variance of the process is stationary.

What is such a process called?

Note that every wide-sense stationery (WSS) process has the above property since a WSS process satisfies $k(t, t') = k(\vert t - t' \vert)$ and $k(t, t) = k(0) < \infty$. But the converse is not necessarily valid. Take for instance $k(t, t') = f(\vert t^2 - t'^2 \vert)$ where $f$ is a suitable positive-definite function. A process corresponding to such auto-covariance (if exists) is not WSS, but its variance is constant.